# How to evaluate effective Feynman diagrams in the standard model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory

I was reading the ["Weak Hamiltonian, CP Violation and Rare Decays"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9806471) by Andrzej J. Buras and, in the page 57 I don't understood how he calculate the effective Feynman diagrams for to get the effective operators. Can someone  give me a hint?

Comment: You might consider reading Schwartz (QFT & the Standard Model) chapters 33 through 36, or Weinberg vol 2 chapter 16, Srednicki chapter 29, and Peskin & Schroeder chapter 11